# LAMPP MySQL Ubuntu not running

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, lampp

I have an issue when I restart mysql server :

via the following :

```
/opt/lampp/var/mysql$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.36-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...already running.
After sometime it fails to the following :

/opt/lampp/var/mysql$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status
Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.6.36-0
Apache is running.
MySQL is not running.
ProFTPD is running.
```

When I check the bin error log , I get the following error =>

```
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"t4a"."tbl_responses"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 2845.
InnoDB: 2 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 0 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 3472600576
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140277711759104 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140277711759104 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.38-83.0 started; log sequence number 342276173866
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140277623092992 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: Starting recovery for XA transactions...
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: Transaction 3472595085 in prepared state after recovery
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: Transaction 3472595084 in prepared state after recovery
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: Transaction contains changes to 1 rows
2018-10-11 10:00:41 7f958a455740  InnoDB: 2 transactions in prepared state after recovery
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [Note] Found 2 prepared transaction(s) in InnoDB
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [ERROR] Found 2 prepared transactions! It means that mysqld was not shut down properly last time and critical recovery information (last binlog or tc.log file) was manually deleted after a crash. You have to start mysqld with --tc-heuristic-recover switch to commit or rollback pending transactions.
2018-10-11 10:00:41 140280246654784 [ERROR] Aborting
```

How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Have you read the error log you posted. It gives an instruction of how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It means that mysqld was not shut down properly last time and critical recovery information (last binlog or tc.log file) was manually deleted after a crash. You have to start mysqld with `--tc-heuristic-recover` switch to commit or rollback pending transactions

Comment: Well done copy pasting part of the question.  Not sure weather to downvote or upvote for irony 

Comment: I tried the  following  : /opt/lampp/var/mysql$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql mysqld_safe --tc-heuristic-recover=COMMIT   but it didn't work

Comment: Also the  following :  /opt/lampp/var/mysql$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql mysqld_safe --tc-heuristic-recover=ROLLBACK

Comment: You must pass the switch directly to the binary and not to the startup script

Comment: @N.D. Please post how you 'pass the switch directly to the binary' to save others TIME trying to discover how this is accomplished with your specific solution.